# How to force System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(string path) to use / in Windows Environment

Tags: asp.net, .net

I want to have slash instead of backslash, because my application communicates with a ftp not allowing backslash as directory-seperator.

Is there any shortcut/configuration without writing my own method?

Comment: Why not just make a `myString.Replace("\\", "/")` call?

Comment: because i won't do this in my whole code. Plus, it costs a lot more performance than changing it before paths are written/determined. Also, it will replace it everytime i upload a file and there will be a bunch to upload every time the script runs.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a way to get the file system to return you the value in a way that it doesn't understand or support. The easiest way I could think to do it, would be to create an extension method and does what Tejs suggested. Then just use that extension method everywhere that you need to get GetDirectoryName

Comment: The OS needs the \, so something has to replace it somewhere.  Whether you do it or something else does, it's the same performance issue.  And, if you do it in the call to GetDirectoryName, then you only have to do it in that one place.

Comment: You should use the `Uri` class.

Comment: well, on the entire FTP protocol the string Replace will most probably not be noticed

Comment: @Daniel: Uri has no GetDirectoryName method. I need that one hard :)

Comment: @Pleun: Yeah, but the script will take longer to run. (Yes it won't be much, but i am addicted to performance issues... )

Comment: @AnthonyShaw first — Windows does support both backslashes and slashes as separators. Second — unfortunately C# doesn't allow static extension methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stealing @Tejs comment as an answer.

Since `GetDirectoryName` returns a string, you can simply replace the backslashes with the symbol you prefer:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Replace("\\", "/")
```

Comment: Hmm. Ok. So i have to do it that way. I neither like it nor i prefer it, but i have to :( @Performance issue: There is a difference between telling a method to use a specific char and replacing a char wtih another.

Comment: Yes, there's a performance hit in string manipulation. Will you feel it? Only if you're doing **literally billions** of these operations every second.

Comment: Yeah, sure. But if i add this little one, another one, another one,... in Germany we say: "Kleinvieh macht auch mist!" translates into "Mickle makes a muckle!"

Comment: @TaiKahar in holland we say perfect is the enemy of good. This is really something that is not noticable. If you are concerned about performance of ftp by a faster dsl line....

Comment: I can agree with that @Pleun :) It's all about principles.